# How to return updated partial View along with its parent View (postback)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Parent View with 2 partial views inside it, the partial views contains few textbox and a button, when I submit the button, the partial views will show some message. Code below :

View :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of Test.ParentModels)" %>

<% Html.RenderPartial("LogIn", Model.LoginModel)%>
<% Html.RenderPartial("Register", Model.RegisterModel)%>
```

Model :

```
public class LoginModel
{
    //code here
}

public class RegisterModel
{
    //code here
}

public class ParentModel
{
    public LoginModel LoginModel {get; set;}
    public RegisterModel RegisterModel {get; set;}
}
```

Controller :

```
//LogIn page will call this method on submit
public LogIn(LoginModel model) 
{
    //do something that changed Login html view
    return View("LogIn", model);
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to return the updated partial view along with its parent (postback) and I don't want to use ajax to achieve this. I tried both return View("LogIn", model) and return PartialView("LogIn", model), both only shows the partial view without its parent. Any help will be appreciated and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Did you try: return View("ParentViewName",parentModel);

Comment: yes, I tried to return View("parentview", new ParentModels()) but all the changes happened in LogIn is gone because I reset the object by passing new models.

Comment: That's expected behavior, since you are sending "new ParentModels()". If you want to persist state then set those values to the ParentModel object and return view. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do a full page postback, though you postback from the partialview part, in the corresponding Action Method you need to return the Main View(which has two partials in your case) and **also capture whatever state required from postback and set it to the model object ( if you need to persist the state)** as expected by the Main View.

E.g.

```
return View("ParentViewName",objParentModel);
```

Comment: I'm still confused, how do I return the objParentModel when my child view doesn't know anything about parentModel. Here's my partial view code :

    
    <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of      Test.LogInModel)" %>
    

As you can see my partial view inherits LogInModel, not ParentModel.

Comment: You may get parentModel state similar to how are you getting it on first page load. OR you may take ParentModel as POST Action methods's parameter (Login in your case), if it doesn't disturb your application flow.